# Upload to a PHP Server, using Ajax ( XMLHttp POST)

Tags: php, ajax, upload, xmlhttprequest

Right now i'm using the below method to Upload a file to PHP

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://sserver.com/fileupload.php" method="POST">

<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000000" />
<input type="hidden" name="filename" value="file_uploaded.gif" />
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="foobar"/>
 Please choose a file:
 <input name="uploaded" type="file" /><br />
 <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
 </form>
```

I read the `$_POST` and `$_FILE` in php to complete upload like this.

```
$target = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/test/upload/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ; 
 echo $target;
 $ok=1; 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 {
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']). " has been uploaded";
 } 
 else {
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
 }
```

My questions is , can i change the above said code (HTML) to an Ajax XMLHttpRequest without changes in `PHP`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot send files to the server via AJAX alone. This is because Javascript (when run in a browser) does not have access to the host's file system.

There are ways to make AJAX-style upload boxes using iframes, where the whole page is not reloaded during an upload, but this is not a simple task in itself. [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) provides a couple of libraries to make this easier.

**EDIT** As ThiefMaster rightly points out [HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) provides mechanisms for doing this more neatly.

Comment: You can upload files via AJAX in recent browsers. The user still needs to select the file though.